# Datagrid styling row colors for changed values

Tags: wpf, datagrid, colors, styles

I'm looking for a way to change the `Color` of a complete row in a WPF `DataGrid`.
My implementation requires configuration information and I want to make it obvious to the user that a value has changed. I'm wanting the default `Color` to be black, but to display red when a value has changed.

I have a property, `IsChanged`, which reflects the status of the item which I wish to use to `Style` the `Row`.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use a `DataTrigger` to set the background when `IsChanged` is true.
Something like:

```
<Style>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChanged}" Value="true">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF0000" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You will also need to make the IsChanged property a [Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms752914.aspx) to allow binding to it.

Comment: Making it a DP is usually *not* a good idea, just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.